# NgFor show first element on start - Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, row, ngfor

I have row of inputs and dropdowns that I generate each time i click on "Add row" button. With other button I submit complete data and you can see it in console.log. as array of objects where each object is practically that row.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

But I need it to look like this:

[image]

I use this in popup and I need to show first row immediately when popup opens and every other row should be generated after I click on "Add row" button.
In the end, when I submit all, first row should be placed first in array and then rest of the generated rows.

Is there any way to alter this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hjTIYMV0TkMRZXp3U6h4?p=preview) with index, or there is some other solution?

Arrays look like this:

```
 0: {name: "A", data: "123", num: "number1", char: "letter1"}
  1: {name: "B", data: "234", num: "number2", char: "letter2"}
  2: {name: "C", data: "345", num: "number3", char: "letter3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement ngOnInit and add the properties[0] as a empty property, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.properties[0] = this.property;
}
```

Example on this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rKkZ6K1ikTBmkvj9vjqv?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I remember your plunkr ! I believe I'm the one that corrected it actually. You should have asked on your other question !

To force a value on your selects as default, give a value to the model bound to your select. For instance, when you create a new row, set the value of your model to the first option of your selects.

**[Something like this.](https://plnkr.co/edit/hjTIYMV0TkMRZXp3U6h4?p=preview)**

```
createRow(){
  this.properties.push({ 
    name:"",
    data: "",
    num: this.numberTypes[0],
    char: this.charTypes[0]
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey man, great to see you ...Completely forgot that I can post additional questions on same topic... Cassiano just gave me answer but you just solve other problem that i was looking for. Many times thanks!!!